# Extend User model in Django 1.5

Tags: django

I have several different user models which are in need of login and registration, and I used `OneToOneField` in Django before, but I felt it to be quite unclean, on each registration, I need add to both `auth.User` and my own user tables manually. Can there be a better way to do it? I've read the docs, there are several ways, but I'm confused which is the best for my situation?

Thanks!